# What is the probability I feel sick on seven different days on seven different weeks?

Tags: probability

Assuming I feel sick once a week, what is the probability I feel sick on seven different days on seven different weeks?

For example:
Week 1: monday
Week 2: tuesday
Week 3: wednesday
Week 4: thursday
Week 5: friday
Week 6: saturday
Week 7: sunday

I'm pretty confused about statistical dependency.

Comment: Is the day on which you feel sick in a particular week uniformly distributed?  Or does taco tuesday give you food poisoning every single week?

Comment: Next question... Is it always exactly one day per week that you feel sick?  Or do you simply feel sick once a week *on average* with some weeks you feeling sick twice or three times while other weeks you don't feel sick at all.  Next... is the result of each week independent from every other week?  Finally... are we just considering a timespan of exactly seven weeks?  Or are we talking about over the course of a year of your feeling sick once a week, what is the probability that there are seven of those fifty weeks where you feel sick on different days?

Comment: Now... a properly formulated math question... Picking a function from $\{1,2,\dots,7\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,7\}$ uniformly at random, the probability that the function was a permutation will be $\dfrac{7!}{7^7}$.  That appears to be the question you *mean* to ask, just with a different flavor.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly once a week I feel sick and one sickness does not affect the others. And sorry about my notation, I assumed the channel tag to be open enough for this kind of rookie questions ("For basic questions about probability and for questions about calculating a probability, expected value, variance, standard deviation, or similar quantity.").

Comment: It is not that it is a rookie question, it is that it is an ambiguously worded question which requires a great deal of assumptions or rewriting to transform into a properly written question.

Comment: You should definitiely see a doctor!

Comment: Ops! Sorry about that JMoravitz, didn't meant. I assume I wasn't clear enough on my question. Will try my best next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing comments,

Assuming that a correct rephrasing of the question is "*If choosing a function from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ uniformly at random, what is the probability that the randomly chosen function is a permutation?*" then we recognize that the problem statement makes it clear that every function on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ is equally likely to occur.  This allows us to calculate probabilities via counting techniques.

It is well known that the number of functions from a domain $A$ to a codomain $B$ is equal to $|B|^{|A|}$ (*seen by rule of product*).  For us, this is $7^7$ different equally likely functions to have occurred.

> It is for this reason that the notation $B^A$ with $A$ and $B$ as sets is used by some authors to denote the set of functions from $A$ to $B$, giving the convenient result for counting that $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$

It is also well known that the number of permutations on a set $A$ is equal to $|A|!$.  For us, this is $7!$ different permutations which could have occurred.

Now, remembering that when dealing with a sample space $S$ where each outcome in the sample space is equally likely to occur, we have the probability of an event $A$ as occurring will be

$$Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$$

> Recall that this is *invalid to use* in the event that the outcomes in the sample space are *not* known to be equally likely to occur.  There are two outcomes to the lottery: you win or you lose.  The probability of winning the lottery is not $\frac{1}{2}$ however.

Using our counts from before, this yields a probability of:

$$\dfrac{7!}{7^7}$$

---

A rephrasing of your question which keeps the flavor but also the needed rigor and clarifications:

> In each of seven weeks, our person gets sick one of those days.  Within each week the day that our person gets sick occurs uniformly at random and the days in which the person gets sick from one week to another are independent of one another.  What is the probability that among those seven weeks our person has gotten sick exactly once on each day of the week?

Note, the explicit reference to the independence of the outcomes per week and the explicit reference to which day within each week having been uniformly distributed and explicit reference to the timetable over which this story occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much.